# How can I RE-ENABLE USB boot ...?

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb, bootloader, usb-installation

I have made a bootable USB. I have made 100s of them before. I have a dual boot pc, Kali and Ubuntu.

I want to reinstall Kali from USB (alongside my UBUNTU), but the computer will not boot to USB anymore. Burning ISO to DVD is really absurd.

Why can't I boot to USB anymore?

Answer (score 3):

1. Power off your computer.
2. Power On, watch the startup screen.
3. Press the key, usually  <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd>, to enter your BIOS, and look for "Boot Devices". **YMMV**.

Your goal is to enable USB boot, or move USB Boot above Hard Disk Boot in the Boot Order list.

This is not a Ubuntu question.

Comment: USB is disabled in bios, yet I use the USB ports everyday. Everyday. It is an Ubuntu question. I can't and won't install Ubuntu on my laptop if I know I'll lose USB boot. This isn't a BIOS question.

Comment: Try enabling USB in your BIOS. The decision on where to read the initial boot image (disk, USB, CDROM, Floppy) is made by the BIOS. Ubuntu is not even running when the choice is made.

Comment: @M.J.Banks: please follow above advice.  Your statement looks like "why doesn't my car start?  No, I'm not using my ignition key!"